# I have on error Firebase "bucketstorage" when I git clone project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have git clone a React+ Firebase project.
When launching the project, I get this error:

Server Error
FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: No default bucket found. Did you set the 'storageBucket' property when initializing the app? (storage/no-default-bucket)

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

Comment: If it is possible, please share more information on how you initialize Firebase Storage in your react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you put your bucket URL on your app?

Reference:

1. [Google Storage Jacascript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start#web-version-9)

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
// See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#config-object
const firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
  storageBucket: ''
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


// Initialize Cloud Storage and get a reference to the service
const storage = getStorage(app);
```

[image]